# Storing lots of emails (including body) in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, email, nosql

I need to store let's say 1000 emails everyday, these emails need to belong to a specific user but also be searchable to everyone.

Can MySQL do this? Will it slow down too much? Do I need to use noSQL? Or a combination or both? What's the proper way of doing this? I would prefer just MySQL if possible.

Comment: 1000 emails per day is peanuts. If you were talking about tens of millions per day it might be worth thinking about alternatives. As it is, mysql is completely fine.

Comment: @DiegoBasch So I can store gigabytes of emails in a MySQL table and it'll still be responsive?

Comment: @StephenSarcsamKamenar https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-size-limit.html you can store TB's of data in a MySQL database. Responsiveness is another matter obviously depends on spec of your system what queries you are running e.t.c. MySQL is widely used for massive systems such as Facebook http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/11/4/facebook-at-13-million-aqueries-per-second-recommends-minimiz.html

Comment: Putting the email in is easy. You may have to do some work to index the message text though.

Comment: Instead of storing email in a SQL database, did you consider sharing read-only access to the email?  Most mail platforms offer one or more ways to do that, and it seems simpler. If you use something like Gmail, you can offload all the processing and infrastructure to Google. Saves money. (If it works for you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can MySQL do this

Yes, MySQL can do this.

> Will it slow down too much?

That depends on how much is too much, and how you will be setting things up.

> Do I need to use noSQL? Or a combination or both?

No need to use NoSQL or a combination of both.

> What's the proper way of doing this? I would prefer just MySQL if possible.

The proper way depends on all your requirements and expertise.  But it is quite possible to use MySQL to do that.